# Summarize multiple survey questions responses in a single table with percentages

Tags: python, pandas

I am a pandas novice working with survey data and would like to summarize % of positive responses to multiple questions in a single table. I have looked at groupby and pivot but still stuck.

Answers to survey questions are either 1 (yes) or 0 (no)
I would like to:

- group responses by age group
- have the cells in the table represent the % of respondents for an age group that answer 1 (yes)

Sample data:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'AgeBand':['25 to 34', '25 to 34', '35 to 44', '65 to 74'],'LikesJam':[1,0,0,1],'LikesPeanutButter':[0,0,0,1]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

x=df.groupby(['AgeBand'])[['LikesJam','LikesPeanutButter']].sum()
print(x)
     
          LikesJam  LikesPeanutButter
AgeBand                              
25 to 34         1                  0
35 to 44         0                  0
65 to 74         1                  1

Desired Output:

          LikesJam  LikesPeanutButter
AgeBand                              
25 to 34        50%                 0%
35 to 44         0%                 0%
65 to 74       100%               100%
```

My goal is to easily compare age groups across several questions - if there is a better way to approach the problem I welcome suggestions. Thanks!

Comment: why did "65 to 74" group's `LikesJam` share become 100%?

Comment: @enke, there's only one "65 to 74" entry.

Comment: First question I have ever asked here and really appreciate such a prompt response!

I ended up using tlgs original answer :
groupby("age").agg(lambda x: f"{int(x.sum() / x.count() * 100)}%")   

As I now understand it, because the values are 0 or 1, using mean will give the same results?

Comment: @FrankOnkyo, yes, you're correct; furthermore, I've changed my answer to use the `mean` as its more elegant solution. Don't forget to vote up/accept the answers you've found helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the clarity - sorry I am too new - it wont let me vote

Answer (score 2):

The % of respondents is the [mean](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.mean.html):

```
x = df.groupby('AgeBand')[['LikesJam', 'LikesPeanutButter']].mean()

          LikesJam  LikesPeanutButter
AgeBand                              
25 to 34       0.5                0.0
35 to 44       0.0                0.0
65 to 74       1.0                1.0
```

---

To format the values [applymap](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html) can be used to apply a format string to each value in the resulting DataFrame:

```
x = (
    df.groupby('AgeBand')[['LikesJam', 'LikesPeanutButter']].mean()
        .applymap('{:.0%}'.format)
)

         LikesJam LikesPeanutButter
AgeBand                            
25 to 34      50%                0%
35 to 44       0%                0%
65 to 74     100%              100%
```

*Note: the data type has been modified from number (float) to string (object) and can no longer be used for mathematical operations.

Alternatively, an [option context](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.option_context.html) can be used to change the way that the values are *displayed* without changing the actual numeric values in the DataFrame:

```
x = df.groupby('AgeBand')[['LikesJam', 'LikesPeanutButter']].mean()

with pd.option_context('display.float_format', '{:.0%}'.format):
    print(x)

          LikesJam  LikesPeanutButter
AgeBand                              
25 to 34       50%                 0%
35 to 44        0%                 0%
65 to 74      100%               100%
```

*Note: only the display has been changed, the underlying values are still float and can still be used in any mathematical computations. Printing (or otherwise displaying) the DataFrame outside the `option_context` will still show the numeric values.

Answer (score 1):

You're close with the `groupby`! In your case, the percentage of respondants can be achieved using the `mean` aggregating function.

```py
>>> df.groupby("AgeBand").mean() * 100
          LikesJam  LikesPeanutButter
AgeBand
25 to 34      50.0                0.0
35 to 44       0.0                0.0
65 to 74     100.0              100.0
```

To only get the integer part plus the percent sign, you can cast your values using `astype(int)` and `astype(str)` and then concatenating `%`:

```py
>>> (df.groupby("AgeBand").mean() * 100).astype(int).astype(str) + "%" 
         LikesJam LikesPeanutButter
AgeBand
25 to 34      50%                0%
35 to 44       0%                0%
65 to 74     100%              100%
```